# Pass Message from Parent to Child

Tags: components, parent-child, svelte

I have a parent component with many child components repeated using an `{#each} ... {/each}` block, which receives updates from a webhook. I would like to propagate an update (which has an ID) into the child with the same ID. At first, I passed the update message as a prop, then checked if that prop had the same ID in the children. That felt inefficient since each child would have to process the message intended for only one child.

I then decided to use the module context feature, which allowed me to avoid checking in each component (demonstrated on the Svelte REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/9215d2bf87464c7682c6de60d9f88b95?version=3.50.1)). I'm pretty satisfied with this solution, but I'm wondering if there is a better or more streamlined (or official!) way to do this since I imagine this is a pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `module` script for this is a bad idea. It means you can only have one instance of the component that uses said static context variables without causing conflicts.

The proper approach is to use [`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) in the parent and [`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getcontext) in the child (or any descendant) to get access to a shared object.

You can use stores in the context to preserve reactivity or use something like an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) instance to pass events.